# How to create mysql dynamc pivot rows to colum

Tags: java, mysql, database, select, distinct

I am looking to solve the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    _2_12_company.companyInitials,
    _2_05_comptype.typeInitials
FROM
    _2_12_company,
    _2_05_comptype,
    _2_19_companycomptype
WHERE
    _2_12_company.id = _2_19_companycomptype.companyID 
   AND _2_05_comptype.id = _2_19_companycomptype.typeID
```

and here is the result

```
AMAZON  |  MICROSOFT
AMAZON  |  FACEBOOK
AMAZON  |  ALI EXPRESS
```

but I want the result to be like below in a dynamic fashion

```
AMAZON  |  MICROSOFT/FACEBOOK/ALI EXPRESS
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean by "dynamic" result? What do the "|" and the "/" symbol mean?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for aggregation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.companyInitials,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.typeInitials ORDER BY t.id SEPARATOR '/') typeInitials
FROM
    _2_12_company c
    INNER JOIN  _2_19_companycomptype ct 
        ON c.id = ct.companyID
    INNER JOIN _2_05_comptype t 
        ON t.id = ct.typeID
GROUP BY c.companyInitials
```

Notes:

- *always* use explicit, standard joins (with the `ON` keyword) instead of old-school, implicit joins; this has been a best practice since more than 25 years
- table aliases make the query easier to write, read and maintain